# Migration to Media Temple (dv) from (gs) - 777 Permissions issue

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, cakephp, mediatemple

I just migrated my website (built on CakePHP) from Media Temple's (gs) server to (dv). I 
got an error that the /tmp/cache folder is not writable. Changing the 
permissions to 777 fixes this error - however it seems unsafe (is this 
true?). On the (gs) I didn't have to give write access to "Everyone". So it seems the webserver is 
neither the user or belongs to the group.

**How come the server can't write to the cache file and how can I make it so that the web server can write to the tmp folder without setting permissions to 777?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before changing too much around, why not ask their tech support directly? They may have a suggestion that will save you from possibly changing ownership or making things world writable.

A Google search came up with a related issue where you had to have /tmp/cache created by the user for the domain vs creating it as root.

Comment: Do you mind pasting the link you found? I'll ask MT as well, I was just hoping SF would be faster :)

Comment: I think this is what I found before, although it is not specific to CakePHP: http://drupal.org/node/169840 but note "As a result, you can't even fix the problem yourself without the assistance of the webhost provider." That's why I figured it might be best to check with them first.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yes, they got back to me:

(1) Connect to your server as the root user and open up /etc/group in a text editor.

(2) Find the line that appears similar to: psacln:x:2523:

(3) Add the following groups (do not change the groupID number): psacln:x:2523:apache,psaftp,psaadm

(4) Grant group write access to any folders

(5) Restart the apache service.